# how to check firebase auth before routeProvider send to page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, route-provider

I want a route to check and see if a Firebase user is signed in before it redirects someone to the /map.html page.

```
.when('/map', {
            templateUrl: 'views/map.html',
            controller: 'MapCtrl',
            resolve: {
                loggedIn: onlyLoggedIn()
            }

        });
```

I have tried using resolve (see code above) but I only get errors from the onlyLoggedIn() function that say "user is not defined". User is defined and if I try to pass in user to the function I get an error "Unknown provider: user"

```
var onlyLoggedIn = function ($location,$q,user) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log("well: "+user);
    if (user) {
        console.log("user is signed in ");
        deferred.resolve();
    } else {
        deferred.reject();
        $location.url('/signup');
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

How should I go about checking if a user is signed in with firebase before routing them to the /map page?

Firebase gives me the user variable and in 'other' places in my app it works, so the problem isn't user not being defined, but my onlyLoggedIn function not "getting" it(?)

Comment: Which version of the FIrebase SDK are you using? Which version of AngularFIre are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Security rules in Firebase can prevent the page from data from being viewed without permission. You need a client-side solution to redirect the page. You do in routes.
This is complete code for the [Angular Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed)

This is simple code demonstration. I hope that will work for you.

```
angular.module('myApp.routes', ['ngRoute', 'simpleLogin'])

  .constant('ROUTES', {
    '/home': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      resolve: {
        // forces the page to wait for this promise to resolve before controller is loaded
        // the controller can then inject `user` as a dependency. This could also be done
        // in the controller, but this makes things cleaner (controller doesn't need to worry
        // about auth status or timing of displaying its UI components)
        user: ['simpleLogin', function(simpleLogin) {
          return simpleLogin.getUser();
        }]
      }
    },
    '/chat': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/chat.html',
      controller: 'ChatCtrl'
    },
    '/login': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    },
    '/account': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/account.html',
      controller: 'AccountCtrl',
      // require user to be logged in to view this route
      // the whenAuthenticated method below will resolve the current user
      // before this controller loads and redirect if necessary
      authRequired: true
    }
  })

  /**
   * Adds a special `whenAuthenticated` method onto $routeProvider. This special method,
   * when called, invokes the requireUser() service (see simpleLogin.js).
   *
   * The promise either resolves to the authenticated user object and makes it available to
   * dependency injection (see AuthCtrl), or rejects the promise if user is not logged in,
   * forcing a redirect to the /login page
   */
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    // credits for this idea: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/dPr9BpIZID0/MgWVluo_Tg8J
    // unfortunately, a decorator cannot be use here because they are not applied until after
    // the .config calls resolve, so they can't be used during route configuration, so we have
    // to hack it directly onto the $routeProvider object
    $routeProvider.whenAuthenticated = function(path, route) {
      route.resolve = route.resolve || {};
      route.resolve.user = ['requireUser', function(requireUser) {
        return requireUser();
      }];
      $routeProvider.when(path, route);
    }
  }])

  // configure views; the authRequired parameter is used for specifying pages
  // which should only be available while logged in
  .config(['$routeProvider', 'ROUTES', function($routeProvider, ROUTES) {
    angular.forEach(ROUTES, function(route, path) {
      if( route.authRequired ) {
        // adds a {resolve: user: {...}} promise which is rejected if
        // the user is not authenticated or fulfills with the user object
        // on success (the user object is then available to dependency injection)
        $routeProvider.whenAuthenticated(path, route);
      }
      else {
        // all other routes are added normally
        $routeProvider.when(path, route);
      }
    });
    // routes which are not in our map are redirected to /home
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
  }])

  /**
   * Apply some route security. Any route's resolve method can reject the promise with
   * { authRequired: true } to force a redirect. This method enforces that and also watches
   * for changes in auth status which might require us to navigate away from a path
   * that we can no longer view.
   */
  .run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'simpleLogin', 'ROUTES', 'loginRedirectPath',
    function($rootScope, $location, simpleLogin, ROUTES, loginRedirectPath) {
      // watch for login status changes and redirect if appropriate
      simpleLogin.watch(check, $rootScope);

      // some of our routes may reject resolve promises with the special {authRequired: true} error
      // this redirects to the login page whenever that is encountered
      $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(e, next, prev, err) {
        if( angular.isObject(err) && err.authRequired ) {
          $location.path(loginRedirectPath);
        }
      });

      function check(user) {
        if( !user && authRequired($location.path()) ) {
          $location.path(loginRedirectPath);
        }
      }

      function authRequired(path) {
        return ROUTES.hasOwnProperty(path) && ROUTES[path].authRequired;
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: thanks for the info, but  simpleLogin.js isn't in the link you provided.